# How to ensure string ends with a certain substring in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

I'm processing a set of strings in a for loop, but I want to make sure the strings end with `'.jpg'`, so in some cases the string is in the format `str = 'filename.jpg.mat'`, in this case, I need to detect the last 4 characters as redundant, hence I need to convert str to `'filename.jpg'`

In other words, I'm looking for a function in this form:

```
function new_str = fix_end(str, wanted_ending)
```

So when I call

```
fix_end('filename.jpg.mat', '.jpg'),
```

it should return `'filename.jpg'`.

Is there a MATLAB (fast) way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

### Edit

1. It is safe to assume that `wanted_ending` will only occur once in `str`.
2. The redundant part does not have to be `'.mat'`, it can be anything. So I just want to delete whatever there is after `'.jpg'`.

Comment: try `regexrep` -> `regexprep(filename,'.jpg.mat','.jpg')`

Comment: @GameOfThrows or just `strrep` instead of `regexrep`

Comment: @Dan yes ofc, much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with regular expression replacement ([`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html)). This looks for names that have something after `.jpg` and removes it.

```
names = {'file1.jpg.mat', 'file2.jpg.mat2', 'file3.jpg.mat3', 'file4.jpg'}

newnames = regexprep(names, '(?<=\.jpg).*', '');
%    'file1.jpg'    'file2.jpg'    'file3.jpg'   'file4.jpg'
```

Or more generally, the following which accepts the ending that you want to keep and remove anything that comes afterwards.

```
function new = fix_end(str, ending)
    new = regexprep(str, ['(?<=', regexptranslate('escape', ending), ').*'], '');
end

fix_end('file1.jpg.mat', '.jpg')
%   file1.jpg
```

As a sidenote, if all you *really* need is for all the strings to end in `.jpg`, why not just append `.jpg` to *all* strings regardless of what their previous extension was?

```
new_str = [str, '.jpg'];
```

As suggested by @Mohsen, you can also use the following

```
newnames = regexp(names, '^.*\.jpg', 'match', 'once');
```

Or as a function:

```
function new = fix_end(str, ending)
    new = regexp(str, ['^.*', regexptranslate('escape', ending)], 'match', 'once');
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but the redundant part is not necessarily `'.mat'`, it can be anything.

Comment: The regex can be done on `.jpg.(any string)' I think.

Comment: Yes! Your last suggestion works as a charm :) Thanks. (going to accept in 7 minutes)

Comment: @HalilPazarlama Updated.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized this solution is actually appending a single quote to the beginning of the string. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @HalilPazarlama It shouldn't. Can you post exactly how you're calling it with a string that causes that issue?

Comment: There is an alternative regexp: `newnames = regexp(names, '^.*\.jpg', 'match', 'once')`. It's a bit easier to read and understand than positive lookbehind.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia True. updated to provide that as an alternative.

Comment: @Suever I think it was a problem on my side. Sorry for the late response and thanks for all the help!

Comment: @HalilPazarlama Not a problem! Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for your case

```
function new_str = fix_end(str, wanted_ending)
    new_str = [str(1:strfind(str,wanted_ending)-1), wanted_ending]
end
```

It might be faster to use `strrep` if it's always `.mat` that you want to get rid of so either:

```
strrep(str,'.jpg.mat','.jpg')
```

or

```
strrep(str,'.mat','')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it also clips some part of the filename, hence returns something like `fi.jpg`.

Comment: It works for "normal" inputs but in my case there are all the "dangerous" characters like dashes, equal sign etc. and it was failing on some of them. I think the real problem is with the dots in the original name. here is an example: input: `-abcde.01.jpg.mat`, output: `-abcde.jpg`

Comment: @HalilPazarlama I've edited it with more robust solutions

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab function `fileparts` might be want you want

> fileparts - Parts of file name and path
>
> This MATLAB function returns the path name, file name, and extension for the
>       specified file.
>
> ```
> [pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(filename)`
> ```

For your case:

```
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts('filename.jpg.mat')
pathstr =
 ''
name =
filename.jpg
ext =
.mat
```

And then you can work with `name` and `ext` to your liking.

Comment: Since I asked for a MATLAB way, this seems very appealing too. Is it guaranteed to work even when there are multiple dots in the filename?

Comment: @HalilPazarlama Well, I think it only strips the last part (which is an extension). It is not completely what you want, but I figured `fileparts` needs to be under your attention :)